# How to clone pexpect winsize from current terminal?

Tags: python, perl, expect, pexpect

In Perl's expect module, I can do this:

```
my $login = new Expect;
$login->slave->clone_winsize_from(\*STDIN);
```

What's the equivalent in Python? I see an option for child.setwinsize(row, column), but how do I clone it from STDIN like I can do in Perl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out how to do this:

```
rows, cols = map(int, os.popen('stty size', 'r').read().split())
child.setwinsize(rows, cols)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `raw_input()`, `readline()` or `sys.stdin.readline()` depending on how you get your stdin.

Answer (score 0):

Tks @nerdinary,

its works for me:

```
stconn = 'ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ForwardX11=no root@server'    
conn = pexpect.spawn(stconn, encoding='utf-8')
conn.timeout = 10
rows, cols = map(int, os.popen('stty size', 'r').read().split())
conn.setwinsize(rows, cols)
conn.expect('password:')
```